# Port forwarding Configuration for Webcam

Tags: port-forwarding, dynamic-dns

I have a webcam which is streaming via mjpg-streamer on `http://localhoste:8121/?action=stream`. Now, I'm wishing to access the camera from outside. I'm using an DDNS system and now I have a domain name pointing to my router. On my router, I've set up a port forwarding as below:
[image]

Now, as per the config, I've chosen the host and the port on which the request should be directed to. For HTTP, it is working properly. Say my domain name is mydomain.name.com, I'm able to access a page hosted on Apache on http://mydomain.name.com/test.html. However, I'm not able to view the streaming if I do mydomain.name.com:8121/?action=stream.

Sample output from `netstat -l`:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 *:8121                  *:*                     LISTEN
```

**Selecting the host:**

[image]

My question, Have I wronged in the configuration? If yes, how can I correct it?

Comment: Is your mjpg-streamer only listeing on localhost:8121 or on *:8121? `netstat -l` will tell you. It needs to listen on *, otherwise it won't be accessible except from your machine---even to other machines on your network.

Comment: I've updated the question, yet it is listening on *

Comment: I'm just going to say that you need to be extraordinary careful. If that's pointed at your house people may find out when you are home or not.

Comment: Also, looking at your port forward setup screenshot, I'm somewhat confused... Normally there would be a *LAN* IP address to forward it to in the setup.

Comment: @derobert, you are right, I've added a screenshot above, it's where I select the host

Comment: @SailorCire, i'm currently on testing it, it gonna be secured with password later